# React widget Combobox not updating onFocus with Reduxform

Tags: javascript, combobox, react-redux, redux-form

I actually have 2 combobox ([react-widgets](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/Combobox)) on my reduxform.

My first combobox works perfectly because I fetch my datas onChange.

But when I focus the second one I want my data loaded in it depending on the value of the first one.

The problem is : I have data in the render when I console.log it but the component not rerendering. I have to type something in the field to see my data, it's like only the onchange trigger the rerendering.

Field in the form:

```
<Field
    component={HouseComp}
    name="house"
    currenthouses={currenthousesValue}
    onFocus={getHouses(props)}
    {...props}
 />
```

My component render:

```
 <Combobox id="house"
     data={currenthouses}
     {...input}
  />
```

the getHouses function is a fetch returning something like :

```
props.dispatch(change('form', 'currenthouses',data))
```

the currenthousesValue is from a selector:

```
const currenthousesValue = selector(state, 'currenthouses');
```

I tried to force the update by using componentDidUpdate but even if I see the call of my render function the UI is not refreshing.

I also tried to load the data on "onBlur" from the first one but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to React. But I faced a similar issue in React. In your case when the value of first combo box changes, The value of data attribute of second form also changes. But your second combobox is not re-rendering may be becuase it is not subscribed to componentWillReceiveProps event.

Something like this(taken from my code):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            groups: nextProps.groups,
            invoices_count: nextProps.groups.length
        });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is the same, data is there but I have to type something in the combobox to "render" the list in the UI :/